# How to make a static variable thread-safe

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this static class which contains a static variable (a simple int). I've implemented a `lock()` in the `Run()` method of the threads, so no other threads can access to this class concurrently, but the variable still goes crazy, displaying duplicates, insanely high values, etc.

This is the class:

```
public static class ExplorationManager
{
    public static int Counter = 0;

    public static void ExplorerMaker(List<int[]> validPaths, List<string> myParents, string[,] myExplorationMap, List<int[]> myPositions)
    {
        foreach (var thread in validPaths.Select
        (path => new Explorer(myParents, path, myExplorationMap, myPositions)).
        Select(explorer => new Thread(explorer.Explore)))
            {
                thread.Name = "Thread of " + Counter + " generation";
                Counter++; 
                thread.Start();
    }
}
```

}

Is there a way to make this variable "more" thread-safe?

Comment: _goes crazy, displaying duplicates, insanely high values_ - is not really explainable from this code.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are at least 2 problems that you need to address in order to increase the safety of this type.

The first one is to make `Counter` `private`.  In it's current form the variable is 100% public and it can be mutated by any piece of code in the application.  Today it may be safe but there's nothing protecting you from making a mistake tomorrow.  If you still want other pieces of code to be able to read the property then use an accessor

```
private static int m_counter;
public static int Counter {
  get { return m_counter; }
}
```

The second problem is that `++` isn't a safe operation on a location that is shared amongst threads.  It expands out to the following code

```
Counter = Counter + 1;
```

Which is in reality doing

1. load Counter
2. load 1
3. add
4. store Counter

A thread can be interrupted an virtually any time.  If one thread is interrupted at step 1, 2 or 3 and another thread fully executes the sequence then you will end up adding / storing stale values.  This is why `++` is unsafe. The safe way to increment a shared value amongst threads is to use `Interlocked.Increment`.  It's designed exactly for this purpose

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref m_counter);
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, the problem is with my code? Or are there other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 18):

Use the [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) class:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref Counter);
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `lock` around all reads/writes of your static variable. Something like:

```
public static readonly object CounterLock = new object();

...
lock ( CounterLock )
{
    Counter++;
}
...
```

The point is that *all* reads / writes *must be protected* by the lock - it's not enough to protect a single place because then threads doing reads or writes may still make a change when a lock elsewhere is in effect.

A lock protects a region of code, not a variable, that's why you need a lock everywhere where you access a shared variable.

Note that you cannot lock on your `Counter` variable - you need an instance of a reference type as a lock, not a value type. This is why I used `object` as the lock type (the other answer did the same).

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought that protecting the access to the class from the `Run()` method, actually protected it. Thanks.

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki Yes, you're right. I'll update the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public static class ExplorationManager
{
    public static int Counter = 0;
    private static object _lock = new object();

    public static void ExplorerMaker(List<int[]> validPaths, List<string> myParents, string[,] myExplorationMap, List<int[]> myPositions)
    {
        foreach (var thread in validPaths.Select
        (path => new Explorer(myParents, path, myExplorationMap, myPositions)).
        Select(explorer => new Thread(explorer.Explore)))
            {
                thread.Name = "Thread of " + Counter + " generation";
                lock(_lock)
                {
                    Counter++; 
                    thread.Start();
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Interlocked.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) is another thread-safe option. Much simple to use if you just need counter.

```
var newCounter = Interlocked.Increment(ref Counter)
thread.Name = "Thread of " + (newCounter-1) + " generation";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with static constructor to initialize static variables. It's best practice to provide a separate `locking` object, so you have good control over granularity of locks.