# Do these static application properties need to be locked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

In my web application, I read some settings from an external config file during `Application_Start`, then access them across the application's many methods:

```
namespace Common
{
    public static class CommonConfigSettings
    {
        public static string DataSource { get; set; }
        public static string DatabaseName { get; set; }
        public static string DatabaseUserName { get; set; }
        public static string DatabasePassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

During `Application_Start` these are read from an XML file into the static variable:

```
DataSource = els.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Attribute("key").Value == "DataSource").Attribute("value").Value;
DatabaseName = els.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Attribute("key").Value == "DatabaseName").Attribute("value").Value;
DatabaseUserName = els.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Attribute("key").Value == "DatabaseUserName").Attribute("value").Value;
DatabasePassword = els.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Attribute("key").Value == "DatabasePassword").Attribute("value").Value;
```

In the application they are used as follows:

```
myConn.ConnectionString = string.Format("Persist Security Info=False; User ID={0}; Password={1}; Initial Catalog={2}; Data Source={3}; Connection Timeout=60", 
    CommonConfigSettings.DatabaseUserName, 
    CommonConfigSettings.DatabasePassword, 
    CommonConfigSettings.DatabaseName, 
    CommonConfigSettings.DataSource);
```

At no point in time are the static values written to following `Application_Start` - they are only read back out (although perhaps by 2+ people simultaneously).  There are also no static methods, just properties.  I read about locking and thread safety [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981190/how-to-make-a-static-variable-thread-safe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941181/are-static-variables-thread-safe-c-sharp), but have only confused myself.  Should I implement locking on these values, and if so, at what point please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that those properties are written just once (and prior to all read operations), there is no need for locking.

EDIT: The question is: Will it always be so? If you would come to the need to replace this database access information at runtime, you would run into the problem of non-atomic operations (e.g. reading a new database username and and old password if the writing thread would be interrupted at the right/"wrong" time). May be it would be good to provide a method to return all needed data in a single struct. This method can be provided with a thread locking mechanism in the future if the need would arise...

```
public struct DatabaseAccessData
{
    public string DataSource { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseUserName { get; set; }
    public string DatabasePassword { get; set; }
}

public static class CommonConfigSettings
{        
    private static string DataSource { get; set; }
    private static string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    private static string DatabaseUserName { get; set; }
    private static string DatabasePassword { get; set; }

    public static void SetDatabaseAccessData(DatabaseAccessData data)
    {
        DataSource = data.DataSource;
        DatabaseName = data.DatabaseName;
        DatabaseUserName = data.DatabaseUserName;
        DatabasePassword = data.DatabasePassword;
    }

    public static DatabaseAccessData GetDatabaseAccessData()
    {
        return new DatabaseAccessData
        {
            DataSource = DataSource,
            DatabaseName = DatabaseName,
            DatabaseUserName = DatabaseUserName,
            DatabasePassword = DatabasePassword
        };
    }
```

Let me say that i am not a fan of "static" in this case. If some of your classes depend on having the common configuration settings, you should pass an instance of CommonConfigSettings to them via constructor parameter or property (see "Dependency injection"). I prefer the first, as it is more rigid / strict; you cannot forget to pass an important dependency then.

Comment: Thank you - that's good to know.  Is locking required then when the combination of simultaneous writing and reading is introduced (which makes sense)?

Comment: Just edited for that case. ;-)  
Yes, if simultaneous writing and reading would be the case, you would need to have some locking mechanism.

Comment: *"return all needed data in a single struct"*.  Sorry can you please explain what this means (how its different to what I am already doing)?

Comment: As of now, your reading threads are accessing the single needed properties "DataSource", "DatabaseName" etc. one after another (see your Format call). What i was trying to say is: Don´t allow read access on these single properties, only allow access on a method that returns all needed properties "in a bunch". This central access method can be better controlled later on... You know what a struct is, do you?

Comment: I thought it was very similar to a class.  That's the reason I asked, because I figured my static class was doing pretty much what you said?  Sorry for all the questions, I just want to be absolutely sure I'm doing the right thing